# My custom CMS Layout Template in Magento is not loaded

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have created custom CMS layout for Magento according [this tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/adding_cms_layout_templates). On my localhost(XAMPP on Win7) it is working, but when I have uploaded all 3 files to my web:

- app/code/local/Lorinc/cmsLayout/etc/config.xml
- app/design/frontend/sportsfans01/default/template/page/cmsLayout.phtml
- app/etc/modules/Lorinc_cmsLayout.xml

And it is not working there. 
Here is the code of **config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Lorinc_cmsLayout>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Lorinc_cmsLayout>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <page>
      <layouts>
        <cmsLayout translate="label">
          <label>cmsLayout</label>
          <template>page/cmsLayout.phtml</template>
          <layout_handle>cmsLayout</layout_handle>
        </cmsLayout>
        <!-- add more layouts here -->
      </layouts>
    </page>
  </global>
</config>
```

And here is **Lorinc_cmsLayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Lorinc_cmsLayout>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <depends>
        <Mage_Page />
      </depends>
    </Lorinc_cmsLayout>
  </modules>
</config>
```

I have tried everything. I have changed files and folder permissions (files 0644, folders 0755), i have used [magento-cleanup.php](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions), my cache is disabled, I have tried to logout and login again and nothing works. Any ideas what is wrong there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem finally solved. I already had one custom layout (called HomeLayout) on that page so I just merged that 2 layouts. Here is the code of app/code/local/Lorinc/HomeLayout/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Lorinc_HomeLayout>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Lorinc_HomeLayout>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <page>
      <layouts>
        <Lorinc_HomeLayout translate="label">
          <label>HomeLayout</label>
          <template>page/HomeLayout.phtml</template>
          <layout_handle>HomeLayout</layout_handle>
        </Lorinc_HomeLayout>
        <Lorinc_cmsLayout translate="label">
          <label>cmsLayout</label>
          <template>page/cmsLayout.phtml</template>
          <layout_handle>cmsLayout</layout_handle>
        </Lorinc_cmsLayout>
        <!-- add more layouts here -->
      </layouts>
    </page>
  </global>
</config>
```

And it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

just looked at your question and the first thing I saw is that you have a wrong folder structure:

The path **app/design/frontend/sportsfans01/default/template/page/cmsLayout.phtml**

has to be changed to

**app/design/frontend/default/sportsfans01/template/page/cmsLayout.phtml**

Don't know if its just a typo of yours!

Furthermore you could check the logs of magento:

var/log/exception.log
var/log/system.log

Hope this will help

Regards

Vince

Comment: Hi Vince. Thanks for trying but it did not help. First thing: I am pretty sure, the path is correct, because I use the same path on my localhost and it works and as well I use the same path for another layout and it works too. Just in case I have tried your path, but nothing happened. And second thing. Here is my log when I open CMS > Pages > and click on a page to edit:

Comment: 2013-09-26T17:01:57+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /data/web/virtuals/49304/virtual/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] /data/web/virtuals/49304/virtual/www/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:766
[2] /data/web/virtuals/49304/virtual/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:83
[3] /data/web/virtuals/49304/virtual/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:188
[4] /data/web/virtuals/49304/virtual/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:354
[5] /data/web/virtuals/49304/virtual/www/app/Mage.php:683

Comment: [6] /data/web/virtuals/49304/virtual/www/index.php:87
</pre>     It is not so much help for me. Do you understand something of it?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I found it in **App/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml** for the 1column.phtml layout

```
<global>
    <page>
      <layouts>
        <cmsLayout module="page" translate="label">
          <label>cmsLayout</label>
          <template>page/cmsLayout.phtml</template>
          <layout_handle>page_cmsLayout</layout_handle>
        </cmsLayout>
        <!-- add more layouts here -->
      </layouts>
    </page>
</global>
```

If this won't help please try with changing different theme folder.Be sure to avoid typo mistake.

Comment: Hi chirag. Thanks, but this is not a best solution. When you change some of the core files, you will loose them during update. And second thing. There should be no type in my files, because I just copied them from my localhost, where it works.

Comment: @Posuk13 I was not talking about changing the core file i was just talking that i had found the above snippet from core files so might that helped you in your custom file.But now your issues solved. That 's great.Thanks.